Long-chain polymers for creating large, long-lasting, immortal bubbles
I'm experimenting with different substances to add to a bubble solution to create the largest and longest-lasting bubbles I can make.
Are there any long-chain polymers, whether in their pure form or not, that can be added, or should be avoided?
I understand [that] environment is important in bubble vigor/stamina...my aim here is to discover new substance/ingredient ideas from the vast amount of experience and subject knowledge held by the humans beings down here.

Meh, where does a bubble end and balloon starts?
